# How to keep OWASP HTML sanitizer from limiting line length?

Tags: java, html, sanitization, owasp, html-sanitizing

I have to put several 100000 very old html documents into a web application. I saw great effects while using the OWASP HTML Sanitizer and was able to ensure that properly sanitized HTML is created.
My only problem is that HTML Sanitizer puts a hard limit on the maximum line length. To be exact this is a maximum of 250 byte per line.
Unfortunately this has the effect that some words get split in the middle and this is the same with the displayed html (marked with a caret):

```
This sentence here is perfectly ok. But in the next s entence there is an additional space in the word "sentence".

                                                     ^
```

How can I tell the sanitizer not to end the lines too soon ?

As some of the lines from the originary html are 800 byte or more it would also help if I were able to tell the sanitizer only to insert breaks in whitespace.

Comment: How are you invoking the sanitizer? Check the source for limits, but it seems to me that the examples using HtmlStreamRenderer just read and write buffered streams endlessly. Check the Slashdot policy example.

Comment: I did, and found no limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less an answer, more a confession: the effect of truncating lines was caused by some other part of my code which put a line length limit on the output.

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question. I would suggest you to do this so nobody gets a wrong impression of the tool.

Comment: Good idea, but Stackoverflow recommends not to delete answered posts. Perhaps finding my question will help someone to find out that the sanitizer _does not mess_ with the line lengths  ;-)

Comment: It also *doesn't* make you a sandwich, as well. This answer is specific to your own code, which was not the subject of this question. I vote nuke it.